# In App Subscription: Is there any way to detect which payment method the user used? (i.e. credit card, debit card)

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I am using [this library](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3) for in app billing subscription. I would like to know which transaction method the user used to pay the bill. Is it possible? If yes, how to do that?

As I searched but found nothing regarding this. [Here](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions), I found that there is a field called subscription type. But that is only indicating either the subscription is made through testing account or not.

Comment: Well, I don't think you can get a hold of that information. It may be a privacy issue. But why do u need it anyway??